# Is there a vocal interface system for Ubuntu (able to map voice commands to console commands and parameters)?

Tags: sound, command-line

As far as I can remember, on some of even pretty old cellphones it was possible to say a name to be dialled. From this I conclude that it is possible and not very complex to implement. So, do such a system exist, which listens to voice commands, converts them to console commands according to a predefined map and executes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/speech2text/

As i know it features and language to develop own modules.
You should give it a try.

Comment: For more information: http://simon-listens.org/index.php?id=122&L=1

Comment: Does it work on the console, or only in a graphical environment?

Comment: i think simon is gui only.

Answer (score 3):

Gnome Voice Control:

http://live.gnome.org/GnomeVoiceControl

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-voice-control
```

provides voice control for the GNOME desktop, but I have not been able to find any such system for the console.

Also, GNOME apparently did not feel the need to include any documentation on the above site, so who knows what the thing actually does. Sure dev team, I'd love to spend some hours wading through your code to figure out how to use your applet. [/rant]

Ooh, even better! I installed the applet and added it to my panel. Right-click menu has a Help option. "Great!" thinks I. "Now I can find out how it works."

Here's the text of the help page:

> The Voice Control Applet allows you to control desktop
>         with voice. Just start the recording with applet's menu and connect
>         microphone. Then try to say some commands like:
>
> - Page Up
> - Minimize the window
>
> 1.1. To Add Voice Control Applet to a Panel
>
> 1.2. Getting Help

To add Voice Control Applet to a panel,
      right-click on the panel, then choose Add to
      Panel.  Select Voice Control Applet
      in the Add to the panel dialog, then
      click OK.

The layout of the Voice Control Applet applet varies
 depending on the size and type of panel in which the applet resides.

1.2. Getting Help

> If the voice control applet doesn't work for you,
>       please try to contact developers.
>
> First of all, please check that sound is actually recorded
>           in your system. If no, try to adjust mixer settings.
>
> The applet and SR is quite complex system in the development, so
>           please don't expect much right now.

The great thing about this is that you have to install the applet to see the help page, which tells you how to install the applet and how to get help if you can't install the applet. Very useful, indeed.

Comment: would be nice if you remove unnecessary newline in the codeboxes, because it would be much better to read. (you may also refere to http://svn.berlios.de/viewcvs/festlang/trunk/gnome-voice-control/README?revision=250&view=markup )